# Is it possible to export specific data from a SQL database into preformatted tables in a word doc?

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-word

I am trying to automate a report. I have tables that are populated with data from a sql database. To save time is it possible to generate this report with the table fields already populated from the sql database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use the MySQL ODBC connector. Here's a page from the manual about configuring a datasource that you can use in a Microsoft Word mailmerge or Microsoft Excel:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-examples-tools-with-wordexcel.html

Once you have a datasource, you can follow general instructions from Microsoft about how to import data from that datasource:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-a-table-or-query-as-a-mail-merge-data-source-860ef4bc-e793-4004-8a1b-5c8a34c7e89d

Comment: Giving you references to these guides is as much as I can help. I haven't done this in years, and I don't use Microsoft stuff these days. I don't own a Windows computer.